# Adding a parameter to a new eventhandler

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am creating a dynamic gridview and there is a part that I create a new event handler for edits. I also create a new method for doing the actual edit, but I need to pass it a datatable name as one of the parameters so i can rebind it. I can't figure out where to add that parameter:

```
        GridView gridData = new GridView();
        gridData.ID = "test";
        gridData.AutoGenerateEditButton = true;
        gridData.RowEditing += new GridViewEditEventHandler(grid_RowEditing);
        gridData.DataSource = tbl;
        gridData.DataBind();


protected void grid_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        ((GridView)sender).EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;

        // I don't know how to pass the datasource name to this method, or if its even possible, because i won't ever know the actual gridview name because its dynamically created
        //((GridView)sender).DataSource =  ;
        ((GridView)sender).DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need to unhook the event handler the easiest way to do this is with a lambda expression

```
string dataSourceName = ...;
gridData.RowEditing += (sender, e) => grid_RowEditing(gridData, dataSourceName, e);
        gridData.DataSource = tbl;
        gridData.DataBind();


void grid_RowEditing(GridView gridData, string dataSourceName, GridViewEventArgs e) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Awesome, i just tried that but now under the method for grid_RowEditing, this part ((GridView)sender).EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex; says that the "e" is not in the current context

Comment: @BradHazelnut you can use the same technique to pass `e` around.  I will update my answer

Comment: awesome, that was perfect, thank you very much, now though, when i click on the edit button it just does a post back, do i need to manually put code in there to show all fields in a text box? I thought the AutoGenerateEditButton = true; takes care of that

Comment: @BradHazelnut i'm unfamiliar with how `AutoGenerateEditButton` works. If you post that as another question though I'm sure a lot of the users here who know asp.net will be able to answer that